# Fresh install of Xubuntu on an Acer TravelMate 2410, system will not reboot or shutdown

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, shutdown

I have an old Acer TravelMate 2410 laptop, that was running XP.  I've decided to dump XP, and install Xubuntu.

I did a clean install, and done all the updates that are available.  Everything is running as it should with the exception of reboot and shutdown.  The system will not do either, and it gets stuck.

below is what I've tried so far, and nothing have helped so far.  There is no option in the BIOS to disable booting from LAN, or any other PM settings.

The system has Intel 910GML integrated 3D graphics featuring Intel GMA 900

I changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" acpi=force apm=power_off
```

I did

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

and added

```
apm power_off=1 below lp
```

I also changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

I also changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"
```

I also changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=pci"
```

I also changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=oldboot"
```

Nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: have you checked and installed the latest BIOS for your laptop?  Are there any `dmesg` messages displayed when you invoke a shutdown - should give an idea of what is going on.  Any BIOS options that say "S1/S2 or S3"? - this might need to be set.

Comment: BIOS is at the latest available version, and no option for S1/S2 or S3.  I've added `dmesg' in my question.

Comment: drastic - does booting with the kernel option acpi=oldboot work with the shutdown process? There are a bunch of other kernel boot options as well you can try - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Comment: @fossfreedom that didn't help either.

Comment: what is the outcome of running `sudo shutdown -P now` or `sudo poweroff` ? Still getting a halted system?

Comment: @AndersF.U.Kiær yes on both commands.

Comment: What kernel are you on? Been a lot of changes to acpi recently. You might wanna try solving the problem loading a custom [DSDT.](https://code.google.com/p/aceracpi/wiki/SupportedHardware)

Comment: I have 3.13.0-35-generic, and no that did not change anything.

Comment: I am soon running short on ideas, but i would definitely try to reset \ load default CMOS. I would also try the 3.11 and 3.17rc3 kernels to make sure it is not related to a regression in 3.13.

Comment: I have the same problem with a fresh installed compaq presario F500 with xubuntu 10.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an Acer TravelMate 2410 and this is the solution that worked for me:

1. Open 'Terminal'
2. Type: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
3. Add a new line at the end that says: blacklist wistron_btns
4. Save the file (press 'ctrl+o' and then 'enter')
5. Exit (press 'ctrl+x')
6. Reboot the laptop.

After you restart Ubuntu you can succesfully shutdown your laptop! If you are wondering why you are doing this: The module 'wistron_btns' crashes when you shutdown Ubuntu. It is supposed to manage the WiFi kill switch and "special" buttons on the laptop.

[I found this solution here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217602&page=5)

Comment: This works with releases as recent as 18.04 LTS (perhaps 18.10 too, which I think is the last Ubuntu 32-bit OS, but I'm staying with 18.04 LTS since it will be supported longer).

Answer (score 0):

Disabling of "wistron_btns" also work on Acer Travelmate 2420 & Ubuntu 14.04.

Tested Bootloader Kernel line" "apm=power_off" and "acpi=force", both of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails on any 'sudo' based linux system using

```
sudo shutdown -h -now
```

should put the system into shutdown, tidying up on the way. The alternative is

```
sudo kill -9-1
```

which will do the same thing but with a little more force.

I would have been interested to know if in the above situations these commands worked or not.

David